# Importing a python file as a module from another python file

Tags: python, module

I have the following structure:

```
edgar_sec
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logs
│   ├── requeriments.txt
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── us_states.py
│   │   └── us_stocks_symbol.csv
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── company_info.py
│   │   ├── financial_reports.py
│   │   └── insiders.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── company_info_test.py
│       ├── company_info_test2.py
│       └── sec_insiders.py
```

I want to import `us_states.py` into `company_info_test2.py`, so I'm doing `import edgar_sec.resources.us_states` but I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edgar_sec'`
What is wrong?

Comment: Only a guess. Have you tried `from edgar_sec.resources import us_states`?

Comment: @nomansland008 same error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edgar_sec'```

Comment: You might have better luck with kruserr answer. It seems the tests folder is not "seeing" its parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put tests outside of package

And also tests don't need to be a package

eg.

```
edgar_sec
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logs
│   ├── requeriments.txt
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── us_states.py
│   │   └── us_stocks_symbol.csv
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── company_info.py
│   │   ├── financial_reports.py
│   │   └── insiders.py
└── tests
    ├── company_info_test.py
    ├── company_info_test2.py
    └── sec_insiders.py
```

Also I see that the project does not follow a standard approach to packaging python applications.

You may have better luck following this tutorial on packaging your python projects:

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/